# rsyslog filter severity not working

Tags: linux, logs, syslog, rsyslog

I have following Rsyslog config to send logs to remote servers. Problem is its sending lots of INFO mesg to remote server and i don't want that noise. I am trying to configure filter so it send all severity logs but not INFO.

```
# Ansible managed

$WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog
$template RFC3164fmt,"<%PRI%>%TIMESTAMP% %HOSTNAME% %syslogtag%%msg%"

# Log shipment rsyslog target servers
$ActionQueueFileName ostack-log-01_rsyslog_container-04cb9e3a
$ActionQueueSaveOnShutdown on
$ActionQueueType LinkedList
$ActionResumeRetryCount 250
local7.* @172.28.1.205:514;RFC3164fmt
```

This is what i did and it didn't work.

```
local7.*;local7.!=info @172.28.1.205:514;RFC3164fmt
```

My OS is Centos7.5 Linux

Comment: Try running in debug mode `rsyslogd -dn` and sending a single item. There is a lot of trace output that may give some clue as to what is happening.

Comment: My problem is its production server and trying to avoid running anything call debug :( let me see if i can poke in dev. Do you think my syntax is correct `local7.*;local7.!=info` ?

Comment: Yes the syntax seems ok to me. It is quite possible to run a separate  rsyslogd process as a simple user if you copy the config file and reduce it to a minimum using say `imuxsock` to listen on a socket file, and then sending to it with `logger --socket ...`  I'm sorry I don't  have an example to link to.

Comment: @meuh i found issue why its keep sending `info` logs because syslog severity is saying mesg is `notice` but inside logs its saying `INFO` that got me confused. let me add that in my answer section so it will help other folks too, Thanks for the `logger` hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what happened here, my syslog messages saying `INFO` logs but in tcpdump i found syslog severity saying `notice` and that was my side confusion.

```
local7.*;local7.!=notice;local7.!=info @172.28.1.205:514;RFC3164fmt
```

This is how we can test this rules, using `logger` tool to generate fake logs

```
logger -p 'local7.info' 'This is info logs, Reject it'
logger -p 'local7.notice' 'This is notice logs, Reject it'
logger -p 'local7.error' 'This is error logs and Accept it'
```

Answer (score -1):

You may want to restart rsyslog service after updating it with the filters, if you didn't already did that.

Restart the rsyslog service after updating the rsyslog.conf file.

```
# service rsyslog restart        # CentOS/RHEL 6
# systemctl restart rsyslog
```

Comment: its obvious i have restarted services after changes.